# HTML 'input' tag with type file is not working in mobile. How to fix it?

Tags: android, html

HTML 'input' tag with type file is not working in mobile. How to fix it?

Help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

My code follows below:

```
<body>
  <h1><font color="white">REPORT</font></h1>
  <br><br>
  <form id="f1" action="summary.html">
    <p>
      <b><font color="white">Project Name:</font></b><br>
      <input type="text" name="project" id="project" value="" required="required">
    </p>
    <p>
      <b><font color="white">Report:</font></b><br>
      <input type="file" accept="application/pdf">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

edit 1:
My JS code as follows:

```
function submitData() { 
  var proj = document.getElementById("project").value; 
  if( proj == "") alert("Please enter the required field");
  else document.getElementById("f1").submit();
}
```

Comment: have you using any JS for this.If yes share that code also

Comment: Did you try providing a `name` attribute to your `input type="file"`?

Comment: have you set JS enabled  `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` ?

Comment: @Armel yes I did

Comment: @RamlalS following is the js code I am using   :         function submitData() {
               
                var proj = document.getElementById("project").value; 
                if( proj == "") 
                    alert("Please enter the required field"); 
                 else 
                    document.getElementById("f1").submit();
                   
                 
                
            }

Comment: @shreya Can you please add your JS to your post? Thanks.

Comment: @Armel I added it

Comment: @shreya- did you get it working? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I develop on Ionic framework and had the same problem.
For me, **removing the `accept` input** make things works.
I see that this have a [partial support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept) and shouldn't then be use for Hybride app.

Answer (score 0):

I have try it on my mobile Chrome Browser it have no Problem [look at the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7qiM.jpg)

Comment: its working on the browser but not inside the application